# Search for specific places in Google map with configurable distance

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I have created simple app to localize my location and nearby car washes. The `onMapReady` method looks like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
        location = gpsTracker.getLocation();
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

   @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        final Location myL = new Location("my location");
        myL.setLatitude(myLocation.latitude);
        myL.setLongitude(myLocation.longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("I'm here"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);

    }
```

Also have added a `Google api key` in values:

```
  <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">my_key</string>
```

I'm wondering how to deal with the thing that I'd like to search for nearby car washes in around 5000m (it can be configure by user), display it on map and get some information about them? I know I have to use `google-api-places` but how should the link looks like if I want to specify the distance which I want to look for car washes? Also where should I put this link in app?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search here you will find the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation at: https://developers.google.com/places/
You will find several ways to integrate your app. For standard mobile apps, you can check the Android and iOS integration. 
If you want a more controlled search, you can use the web services integration.
The web services integration is intended for backend integration as will be controlled by transaction from Google.
You can still use the backend integration from your device accepting the query limits per day and when you use the free option, will find some limits about the search.
The full web services integration with no limits on conditions, data and queries per day is payed.
Hope it helps.